# Ionic 2 form wont capture form values

Tags: forms, angular, typescript, ionic2

So I have a form that looks like this. Each input field is the same so theres no need to post all 241 of them.

My problem is that I cant access the from values through something like `formData.general_information_first_name` because it return "" nothing.

All of my fields are returning invalid even when the requirements have been met.

```
<ion-content>
  <form #formData="authForm" (submit)="onSubmit(authForm.value)">
    <ion-item-group>
      <!-- <button light block >{{'HOME | translate'}}</button> -->

      <ion-item-divider light>{{'INFORMATION_TO_COMPLETE_LOAN_APPLICATION' | translate}}</ion-item-divider>

      <ion-item>
        <ion-label fixed="first_name">{{'FIRST_NAME' | translate}}</ion-label>
        <ion-input ngControl="general_information_first_name" type="text" value=""></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

My corresponding .ts file

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {TranslatePipe} from "ng2-translate/ng2-translate";
import {FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormBuilder,  ControlGroup, Validators, AbstractControl} from '@angular/common';
import {CustomValidators} from './custom-validators';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/us-loan/us-loan.html',
  pipes: [TranslatePipe],
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class UsCitizenPage {

    authForm: ControlGroup;
    general_information_first_name: AbstractControl;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.authForm = this.fb.group({
            'general_information_first_name': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, CustomValidators.onlyLetters])]
        });
        this.general_information_first_name = this.authForm.controls['general_information_first_name'];
    }

    onSubmit(formData) {
        console.log('Form submitted is ', formData);
        debugger;
        if(this.authForm.valid) {
            console.log('Submitted value: ', formData);
            debugger;
        }
    }
```

my angular and ionic version information :

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-beta.10",
    "ionic-native": "1.3.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "ng2-translate": "^2.2.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "del": "2.2.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-watch": "4.3.5",
    "ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript": "2.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-fonts-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-html-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-sass-build": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-scripts-copy": "^2.0.0",
    "run-sequence": "1.1.5"
  },
}
```

Comment: You're using `Ionic2-beta.10`... do you consider upgrading to `beta.11`? I'm asking because `beta.11` uses the new Angular 2 Forms API, which makes creating and handling forms much easier...

Comment: @sebaferreras I'd have to look at the change log and see that it wont break to much functionality that's already been in place.

the app is practically done aside from the forms aside from the forms